# JavaScript For Loop not returning anything (not running)?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

Ok so, I've got this for loop in a script tag on my EJS page. The current code looks like this:

```
<script async>
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
    console.log(removeCartItemButtons)
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++){
        console.log('elem')
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log('clicked')
        })
    }
</script>
```

The console.log for the removeCartItemButtons works but the console.log('elem') doesn't run. There are no errors in my cmd nor on the developer tools. I've looked online at different forums to find people doing similar things to me and their's work fine.

I've tried multiple things, and an extra notice is that this is inside the html file and not external.

The end goal of this for loop is to loop through every element with class 'btn-danger' and log when they are clicked.
Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Hi, could it be the list is empty?

Comment: I confirmed the list was not empty by console logging the removeCartItemButtons. This returned a HTMLCollection with the 2 buttons inside.

Comment: @AviaHumble check and run the code snippet in my answer

Answer (score 1):

try running document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger') in the console.

Additional tip: there is a for of loop in js

check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of
basically:

```
for(let button of removeCartItemButtons) {
     button.addListener
}
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot now.

Comment: tried this way and still not worked, and have confirmed there are 2 buttons on my page that could work with it as console logging the document.get... works and shows both elements.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code in Codepen and it worked. I rewrite your code but technically, just used a different syntax. "async" in your script tag can cause the problem, I can't be sure.

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-danger');
[...buttons].forEach(button => {
  console.log('elem')
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be an issue with your HTML code. Run the snippet below, it's working fine

```js
var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
console.log(removeCartItemButtons)
var i;
for (i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
  console.log('elem')
  var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    alert('clicked');
  })
}
```

```html
<button class='btn-danger'>Button</button>
<br/>
<button class='btn-danger'>Button</button>
<br/>
<button class='btn-danger'>Button</button>
<br/>
<button class='btn-danger'>Button</button>
```

Comment: Hm, still not working for me. I forgot to add there is bootstrap on my webpage and I know bootstrap requires stuff like JQuery. I'm not experienced in Bootstrap so not sure if it's that?

Comment: @AviaHumble Bootstrap will not effect the selection of button elements by classname, can you share your html code in your question?

Comment: Ah, fixed it. It didn't seem to like the EJS file I was running it in so I tried another file and it worked. All fixed now.

Comment: Glad to know that Avia (y)

Answer (score 0):

`removeCartItemButtons.length` is 0 because when the snippet ran the DOM was not fully loaded.

Remove `async` and put your script at the end of your html.

Another option is to use an EventListener like `onload` to make sure your buttons exist before changing them.